# Google Docs: Update Project Info via script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've written a script for my daily sheet, to create a copy of the current sheet at the end of each day and copy some of the day's data into tomorrow's sheet. When I open the script editor for the new sheet, the name of the Project has "Copy of" prepended to it. If the users run this every day for an extended period, the sheets will continue to have "Copy" added to the name until the string is too long to save(?).

Is there a way to set the name easily using a script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the example given for [`Sheet.setName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setName%28String%29).